# How to prevent page reload after click on the user generated anchor link in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

I've some user generated HTML documents, created by a WYSIWYG editor, which have relative links to the same Ember app. When I click any of those links, it goes to the link but the page always reloads. Is there any way to prevent this page reload?

Answer (score 3):

You can install the `ember-href-to` addon, it will correctly route clicks on anchors not created using the `link-to` component:

https://github.com/intercom/ember-href-to